# What would a basic Gradle script Kotlin file for a Kotlin JS project look like?

Tags: javascript, gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying to use [Kotlin-DSL](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl) to write a Gradle build script in Kotlin. So far I've seen examples on how this can be done for a Java project. However since I'm developing a React Native app in Kotlin, there isn't any tutorials I've found for making one for Kotlin/JavaScript projects. So what would a **basic** Gradle script Kotlin file for such a purpose look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official Gradle Kotlin DSL repository contains a basic Kotlin/JS sample: https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/tree/master/samples/hello-js

Answer (score 1):

So after quite a bit of researching, I found a [example](https://github.com/guenhter/kotlin-noob/tree/master/kotlin-js) that suited my needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can find tutorial for Kotlin/JS with gradle [here](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/javascript/getting-started-gradle/getting-started-with-gradle.html) on official Kotlin site. Also, you may look at [example](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-examples/tree/master/gradle/js-dce) which shows how to use Kotlin/JS with Gradle and Webpack.

Comment: That's a tutorial solely for Groovy Gradle, not Groovy Kotlin. The example is useful nonetheless.